# Clicking on a link opens a window browser to save a Document, how to set it in way where there's no pop up and can be stored to a specified location?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

When clicking on a link which opens a window browser to save a Document, how to set it in way where there's no window pop up browser being displayed and it can be stored to a specified location?

I would need this for Chrome browser, IE and Mozilla.

This is what I have tried for Chrome:

```
    String downloadFilepath = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\PDF Files\\";
        HashMap<String, Object> chromePrefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        chromePrefs.put("plugins.plugins_disabled", new String[] {"Adobe Flash Player", "Chrome PDF Viewer"});                      
chromePrefs.put("profile.default_content_settings.popups", 0);
    chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);
                            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", chromePrefs);
                            DesiredCapabilities cap = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
                            cap.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
                            cap.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
                            GlobalVars.driver = new ChromeDriver(cap);
```

But it doesnt seem to be working. It still opens the Windows browser pop up and asks for the location.

Answer (score 0):

Even though I was not able to send it through chrome driver, I handled it through ROBOT API. Here's the code the I have written to handle after the browser pops up:

```
String Projectpath=System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println(Projectpath);

        StringSelection ss= new StringSelection(Projectpath+"\\PDFFiles\\");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);
        try{
            Thread.sleep(3000);

            //Perform native keystrokes for Ctrl+V and ENTER Keys
            Robot robot = new Robot();

            /*robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);*/
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```